# Apache Ignite Cache Created but not showing

Tags: c#, caching, ignite

When i am Querying table inside Cache name X, Ignite is not showing cache and says 'table not found'. And When i am creating Cache, Ignite throw error ----
error below------

```
{Apache.Ignite.Core.Client.IgniteClientException: Failed to start cache 
(a cache with the same name is already started): NIFTYNOHLC
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.DecodeResponse[T] 
(Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Binary.IO.BinaryHeapStream stream, 
System.Func`2[T,TResult] readFunc, System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] 
errorFunc) [0x00045] in <cd4215ea392b444fb1a4942a9be1ae6e>:0 
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientSocket.DoOutInOp[T] 
(Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientOp opId, System.Action`1[T] 
writeAction, System.Func`2[T,TResult] readFunc, 
System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] errorFunc) [0x00012] in 
<cd4215ea392b444fb1a4942a9be1ae6e>:0 
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientFailoverSocket.DoOutInOp[T] 
(Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientOp opId, System.Action`1[T] 
writeAction, System.Func`2[T,TResult] readFunc, 
System.Func`3[T1,T2,TResult] errorFunc) [0x00006] in 
<cd4215ea392b444fb1a4942a9be1ae6e>:0 
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.IgniteClient.DoOutInOp[T] 
(Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientOp opId, System.Action`1[T] 
 writeAction, System.Func`2[T,TResult] readFunc) [0x00014] in 
 <cd4215ea392b444fb1a4942a9be1ae6e>:0 
 at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.IgniteClient.DoOutOp 
(Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.ClientOp opId, System.Action`1[T] 
writeAction) [0x00000] in <cd4215ea392b444fb1a4942a9be1ae6e>:0 
at Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.IgniteClient.CreateCache[TK,TV] 
(Apache.Ignite.Core.Client.Cache.CacheClientConfiguration configuration) 
[0x00024] in <cd4215ea392b444fb1a4942a9be1ae6e>:0 
at CheckNewSymbolsAndCreateTable.MainClass.MainOperation_OHLC 
(System.Type 
 type, System.String TableName, System.String TypeName) [0x0008c] in
```

/home/Ghanshyam/Projects/CheckNewSymbolAndCreateTable_Ver_2_0/CheckNewSymbolAndCreateTable_Ver_2_0/Program.cs:467  [StatusCode=CacheExists]}

Comment: Please show your queries and cache configuration.

Comment: I have attached the cache_config in this [link](https://pastebin.com/gY7kgkTi)

Comment: It seems like you're trying to create a cache with name `NIFTYNOHLC`, I can see `Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.IgniteClient.CreateCache` in the stack trace. Nevertheless in your attached example I've noticed `Apache.Ignite.Core.Impl.Client.IgniteClient.GetOrCreateCache`. It's quite different operation. Could you please clarify what method do you use when you see such error?